# How do I make text bigger in a javascript html game?

Tags: javascript, html, text

In my high school game design class we are making javascript games as HTML files and we are making brick break right now, and I am trying to make my text on the screen bigger and I cant figure out how to do it.

this is what I have now for writing text on the screen

```
canvasContext.fillText("SAMPLE TEXT GOES HERE ", 350, 100);
```

and the text is really small. I'd like for it to be bigger. how do i do that?

Comment: Please show more info, html, css and JavaScript, the info you gave is not enough to give you a good answer.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/font

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
canvasContext.font = "20px Georgia";
canvasContext.fillText("SAMPLE TEXT GOES HERE ", 350, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `canvasContext.font = "30px Verdana"`

30px is the font size and `verdana` is the font family.

Answer (score 0):

I expect more detail, but you can regenerate your text like this:

```
canvasContent.fillText("SAMPLE TEXT GOES HERE ", 435, 10);
```

Comment: Try increasing the numbers that are connected to your small text.